# Use Django 1.5 StreamingHttpResponse to deliver reportlab pdf

Tags: django, pdf, reportlab, http-streaming

just wondered if anyone have done pdf generation using reportlab and the new StreamingHttpResponse objects that are supported in Django 1.5;

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects

I am generating lots of pdfs using the normal way as described in the Django docs and using a HttpResponse as a file-like-object;

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/outputting-pdf/

Now just wondering if the new streaming object in Django can be used and even if this is a good idea at all?

/ Jens